Is this a common mode choke
I have this DC/DC converter.
Can you confirm that the choke on the output visible on the picture is a common mode choke?
If yes, my readings and understanding on common mode current is that it exists because there is a return pass for it generally earth.
As this system is not connected to earth and as the minus input and output are tied together, what can be the return path? any other wire of the system?


Earth is not needed. Whatever path the current is flowing in, that's where you have your CM choke in (if needed). As long as the current in your device goes (equally) though red and black, it's a CM.

The part is a ferrite ring.
Looping the wires through it like that does make a common mode choke.

Yes, that's the accurate answer for my unaccurate suggestion! :D

With this answer, I upgraded the question.

Count the turns for each wire. If same number of turns for black and red, CM as Justme says above. If different number of turns, it's both CM+DM. Highly unusual but not impossible.

With this answer, I upgraded the question.
